# How to implement self-locking motor in Gazebo/SDF?

Tags: gazebo, motor, joint, sdformat, gazebo-ignition

I have a model with a few joints controlled by self-locking motors. The joints can be prismatic or revolute, but the real robot has a very high gear ratio in the motors, so the joints are basically self-locking.

How do I implement this in an SDF file?

In URDF of the robot, I have a transmission:

```
<transmission name="lift_transmission">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="lift_j">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="lift_motor">
        <mechanicalReduction>100</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>
```

However, the transmission is not a part of the SDF after URDF->SDF conversion. So the simulator doesn't know anything about it.

**Problem 1:** I use `gazebo_ros_control` to control the motors and that should (in theory) take the `mechanicalReduction` into account. But I don't see any difference in `joint_states/effort` when moving the joint, no matter what reduction ratio I set here. Or does the `joint_state_controller/JointStateController` publish the effort on the output of the joint?

**Problem 2:** I'd like the joint to behave like having this high reduction ratio even without `gazebo_ros_control`. I.e. natively being hard to move by any external force on the joint output. I know this could be achieved by setting high friction and damping for the joint, but in that case, adding a motor would require the motor to overcome these high values, making the effort values nonsensical.

At least for the prismatic joints, I was thinking about converting them to screw joints, but I don't want the rotating behavior of the attached link. So I could continue and connect the link to the screw joint via another joint (revolute, ball...), but that seems overcomplicated.

For revolute/continous joints, maybe the gearbox joint would be the right thing? But AFAIK there's nothing similar for prismatic...

---

I've put together a minimal example to try it out in Gazebo Classic 9 or 11.

`mwe.urdf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<robot name="MWE" xmlns="http://www.ros.org">

<gazebo>
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so" name="gazebo_ros_control"/>
</gazebo>

<link name="base_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" />
    <geometry><box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" /></geometry>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" />
    <geometry><box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" /></geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" />
    <mass value="1000.0"/>
    <inertia ixx="600" iyy="350" izz="650" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0" />
  </inertial>
</link>

<link name="link">
  <visual>
    <geometry><box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/></geometry>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <geometry><box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/></geometry>
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="10.0"/>
    <inertia ixx="2.7" iyy="0.01" izz="2.7" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0" />
  </inertial>
</link>

<joint name="link_j" type="prismatic">
   <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 1"/>
   <parent link="base_link"/>
   <child link="link"/>
   <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
   <limit effort="1000" lower="-0.5" upper="0.0" velocity="0.5"/>
   <!--dynamics damping="10" friction="100"/-->
</joint>

<transmission name="link_transmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="link_j">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="link_motor">
    <mechanicalReduction>100</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>

</robot>
```

`mwe.launch`:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="control" default="true" />

  <rosparam>
    joint_state_controller:
      type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
      publish_rate: 20
    link_position_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
      joint: link_j
      pid: {p: 8000.0, i: 10, d: 100.0}
  </rosparam>

  <param name="robot_model" textfile="$(dirname)/mwe.urdf" />
  <param name="robot_model_sdf" command="gz sdf -v 1.5 -p $(dirname)/mwe.urdf" />

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch" pass_all_args="true"><arg name="verbose" value="true" /></include>

  <node name="spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-sdf -param robot_model_sdf -model MWE" />

  <node name="gazebo_controller_joint_states" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="true" args="joint_state_controller --timeout 60"/>
  <node name="gazebo_controller_link" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="true" args="link_position_controller --timeout 60"/>

  <node name="control" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" args="pub link_position_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 'data: 0.0'" if="$(arg control)" />

</launch>
```

Launching with `roslaunch mwe.launch control:=true`, it starts up Gazebo classic via gazebo_ros, adds gazebo_ros_control controllers for state publishing and PID effort control of the prismatic joint and tries to keep the top link as high as possible, fighting gravity.

At the very start of the simulation, you can see a noticeable drop of the top link position before the PID controller puts it in place. In my view, if the self-locking were implemented, the link should not move even without the PID controller acting on it (`control:=false`). But if the controller were running, it should exert just a minimum effort to keep the link in place, and not too much effort moving it.

Here's a video of the behavior:

[image: wrong behavior]

Answer (score 1):

Self-locking is a phenomenon that to my knowledge only occurs in worm drives. Other gear units such as planetary gears can have a very high friction, and hence be seemingly non-backdrivable, but if you'd apply enough torque they would still backdrive.

Self-locking does not occur for every worm drive, it depends the geometry (pressure angle and lead angle) and the coefficient of friction, see e.g. [here in section 9.4](https://www.sdp-si.com/resources/elements-of-metric-gear-technology/page5.php) for the self-locking condition.

So re. you question: how can I model this?

I had a look at the just-released 'mimic' functionality in Gazebo Harmonic. I'm not 100% sure, but [from this code](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-physics/blob/1445341181e9b81eaacfee504ccc8fed0f949c9a/bullet-featherstone/src/JointFeatures.cc#L454-L457) I conclude that this is implemented as a position constraint, with a very max high impulse to realize the displacement.
In other words: the concept of gear mesh geometry and friction in the gear transmission is not modeled, so the mimic functionality cannot exhibit self-locking.

There's an open [feature request](https://github.com/dartsim/dart/issues/1756) for Dart which states "we need a constraint that applies equal and opposite impulses to each joint in the constraint". So this would implement an impulse constraint rather than a position constraint, which comes closer but still this does not model mesh geometry and friction either so this cannot exhibit self-locking either.

So my conclusion is: unless you implement the physical model of a worm drive, you cannot currently simulate true self-locking behavior in Gazebo.

Obviously, if your goal is just to mimic self-locking *kinematics*, then you could fairly easily implement this with a system plugin similar to the [JointPositionController](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/src/systems/joint_position_controller), but which drives two joints instead of one, based on one input value.

EDIT: you would not even need a custom system plugin; I did not test this, but it should be possible to just use the mimic functionality and apply the JointPositionController to the input joint.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great analysis. I'm interested in dynamics simulation, so position_controllers are not an option. I don't entirely get the relation between self-locking joints and mimic constraints. Are you suggesting to add an invisible "driving" joint with no load at its end and connect it via mimic constraint to the real joint that should be self-locking?

Comment: Well, the way I understood your question is that you want to model a gear transmission between a motor (i.e. a driven link) and an output shaft, and that gear transmission should be self-locking. The 'mimic constraint' in Harmonic is mentioned as "the equivalent of the 'gearbox joint' in Gazebo Classic" in the [release video](https://vimeo.com/868835608#t=1690s). Given self-locking is a physical effect internal in the gearbox, I had a look at how the mimic constraint is implemented to see if the locking behavior could easily be added, which it seems not...

Comment: It's important to understand that self-locking is internal to the gearbox, and cannot be modeled by adding regular friction to the input or output shaft. There's a nice drawing here: [small pitch](https://khkgears.net/new/worm_gear.html#:~:text=When%20the%20lead%20angle%20is%20small) vs [large pitch](https://khkgears.net/new/worm_gear.html#:~:text=When%20the%20lead%20angle%20is%20large). Note the comment on the "Force in red" being small/large wrt. the friction force. This is what causes the self-locking.

Comment: A further remark given the name "lift_transmission": if the intention of this simulation is to actually design and build a physical lift: be aware that relying on self-locking to prevent a load from falling is dangerous. Self-locking is not guaranteed, see e.g. [this article]( https://www.machinedesign.com/motors-drives/article/21834661/selflocking-worm-gears-fact-or-fiction).

Comment: Ah, okay, I haven't seen the mimic-gearbox relationship. So it seems gearbox or screw+revolute would be the closest approximations. I'll give the screw+revolute a try. Well, I try to model a lift, but not a cargo or people lift - just a tool-holding lift. And there is a positional controller attached to it, so even if self-locking fails, it should stay close to the set position.

Comment: Thanks @JRTG, I've awarded you the bounty as you've provided quite a lot of useful information. I'm not, however, marking your answer as accepted, as it doesn't provide a proper solution. I'll report back here if I'll find something that works better.